# How can I get infinite Rare Candy on a LeafGreen cartridge?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

Is there a way to get infinite rare candies in the real Gameboy Advance Leafgreen? (not an emulator where one can more easily put Gameshark codes)
It would be wonderful to have many.

Comment: Do you want it to be legit? Or will you allow cheats? Also, real GBA or emulator?

Comment: Legit methods or cheats.. both are fine as long as they are for real GBA @Deltharis

Comment: Any ideas? @Deltharis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can determine, in FireRed/LeafGreen there are only two repeatable sources of [Rare Candies](http://serebii.net/itemdex/rarecandy.shtml):

The first involves having a having (multiple) Pokemon with the [Pickup ability](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pickup_%28Ability%29#Pok.C3.A9mon_FireRed_and_LeafGreen) in your party. After a battle there is a 10% chance the pokemon with this ability will have picked something up (provided they aren't holding another item). When they pick something up there's a 5% chance that 'something' is a Rare Candy. Having a full team of 6 all having Pickup will increase your odds (simply by having more attempts per battle), but this can be a rather tedious way to grind Rare Candies.

The second method involves traveling to [Resort Gorgeous](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Resort_Gorgeous) and showing Selphy the Pokemon she requests (after rescuing her from [Lost Cave](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lost_Cave)). If you manage to show her the Pokemon, you have a 1 in 6 chance of getting a Rare Candy.

Neither of these options are all that quick, and your time would probably be better spent leveling Pokemon by sending them into battle against a high-leveled opponent (like the Elite 4), and then switching them out before they faint. The only other option to get many (infinite) Rare Candies on the cartridge AFAIK is to get a cheat device like Gameshark for your GBA.

Comment: Alright. Do you know about any other cheats that work on the real GBA which doesn't use Gameshark? Any cheats not necessarily of items of LeafGreen.

Comment: @asker Nope. I am not aware of any such cheat for *any* Pokemon game other than Gen1's MissingNo glitch.

Comment: What is this MissingNo glitch?

Comment: @asker it is the [item duplication glitch](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Item_duplication_glitch), wherein after encountering a glitch Pokemon, the item in the 6th slot of your backpack is increased by 128 (in gen1 the backpack only had one pocket for all items and had limited space). While this is technically triggered by any encounter with any glitch Pokemon, the most common one (at least around my school in 1997/1998) is MissingNo from performing the [Old Man Glitch](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Old_man_glitch)

Comment: Thank you for those links. I wonder how people find these glitches. The sub-heading Cause tells me that its complicated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools for modifying `.sav` files which is how game data is managed in emulators and flash carts. If the requirement is "real gba" and "no gameshark," then you can extract the .sav file from a real gba cartridge, edit it, and write it back.

[This method](https://www.reddit.com/r/Gameboy/comments/8poxzs/gba_save_writer_tool/) uses a nintendo DS and an [R4 card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08KY37SZB).

Once you have a copy of the .sav file, you can load it into your .sav game editor of choice. I like [PKHex](https://projectpokemon.org/home/files/file/1-pkhex/). Add a bunch of rare candies and then write it back to your gba cartridge.